# What is the form of a differential equation in the form of $\frac{dy}{dx} = f(x) + \int_{a}^{b} g(y(x)) dx$

Tags: calculus

I was trying to remove parameters from a second-order ODE and I stumbled on this type of differential equation. Does anyone know what a differential equation of this form would be called or how to even solve it if it's solvable?

$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = f(x) + \int_{a}^{b} g(y(x)) dx
$$

The interesting problem occurs when the RHS has an integral of the independent variable. $f$ and $g$ are arbitrary functions. In my case, everything is defined in the real domain.

Does this form have a name? Is it solvable at all? What are your thoughts on this?

Thanks in advance.

P.S. I will solve the second-order ODE numerically and optimize my parameters.

Comment: The term $\int_a^bg(y(x))dx$ is a constant so the DE is first-order linear that can be solved by integration factor for example, as you probably already know.

Comment: @user7777777 What if the interval of the integral is not set ie it's arbitrary? Would I still go about using an integrating factor?

Comment: Yes as long as they are just constants (not functions of $x.)$

Comment: very bad notation. In the integral, 'x' is a dummy variable bu then 'x' appears outside the integral.

Comment: @P.Lawrence Could you explain what you mean by the dummy variable? The original equation was $\frac{dy}{dx} = wt - \mu\int_{0}^{T}\frac{1}{(y+R)^2}dx$ where y is the variable on both sides w, $\mu$, and R are known constants and T is an arbitrary constant. The initial conditions are $y(0) = 0$ and $\frac{dy}{dx} = 0$ at $x=0$. Unfortunately in this equation, the derivative of y is dependent on y.

Comment: $wt$ is $wx$ in my last comment*.

Comment: This is not a differential equation. It is an integro-differential equation. Picking up on P.Lawrence's comment it should better be written as $$\frac{dy}{dx} = f(x) + \int_{a}^{b} g(y(\color{red}{z}))\,d\color{red}{z}\,.$$